# php parsing with dom

Tags: php, parsing

i'm having a problem parsing a url. i would like to do it with dom but ihave no idea where to start. i want to only parse the src from the following code. any ideas would be great thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/?code-ajax&cd=1145040425"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$src = $doc->documentElement->getAttribute('src');
```

---

XPath example using remote file

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

// Retrieve collections of script nodes
$allScripts  = $xpath->query('//script');
$headScripts = $xpath->query('/html/head/script');
$bodyScripts = $xpath->query('/html/body/script');

// Get all scripts who's src attribute starts with "http://website.com"
$websiteScripts = $xpath->query('//script[starts-with(@src, "http://website.com")]');
if ($websiteScripts->length) {
    // contains one or more matches
    $src = $websiteScripts->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: Weird, can't post anything containing the script tag (corporate firewall maybe). Assume the `$xml` variable contains the string in your question

Comment: @PhilBrown what if i wanted to use this for an external webpage

Comment: @sabrina You can use `DOMDocument::loadXMLFile()` or `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()` depending on the doctype of the page. You would also need to change how you reach the script node as you would be dealing with an entire page and not just one node. You should probably edit your question to better reflect what you're trying to do

Comment: @PhilBrown i tried this but returns a blank page   <?php 
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
 
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->documentElement->getAttribute('src');
?>

Comment: @sabrina That's not how you use an XPath query. I'll edit my answer to show you an example

Comment: @PhilBrown what does Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: End tag : expected '>' mean?

Comment: @sabrina I'd guess the HTML page in question is malformed. Try setting the error handling as you showed in your previous comment

Answer (score 1):

My favorite solution is [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) php library, it is alot simpler to use than PHP's native solution; I say this from experience. It's similar to jQuery in it's syntax and usage.

You may use it like this

```
include('lib/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/?code-ajax&cd=1145040425"></script>');
$scriptsrc = $html->find('script',0)->src;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) Library:

```
<?php
    // include the SimpleHTMLDom library
    include('lib/simple_html_dom.php');

    // our input string
    $input = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://website.com/?code-ajax&cd=1145040425"></script>';

    // create our Object. If reading from a file, use: file_get_html('/path/to/file');
    $doc = str_get_html($input);

    // find the first <script> tag, and echo its 'src' attribute.
    // -- note: calling this with find('script') returns an array
    echo $doc->find('script',0)->src;
?>
```

Comment: It's one of the best things in PHP, along with Hip Hop